# c# Find (fast) items in object list

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have a list (`List<customers>`) that I'm using to find results. This customer class have a GUID (long string), customer name, and some other strings, but when I'm searching for one given UUID it takes so long to return the customer object that matches (long means miliseconds, but a lot)

```
int indx = CustomerList.FindIndex (Customer => Customer.uuid.Equals ("GUID I'm searching"));
```

The problem is that when I'm searching >50000 elements (import constraints) it takes like 30 minutes to find all indexes.

Is there a way to index GUID field, or sort it from that list to make the search faster? (for example just a ArrayIndex - GUID array) that allows to search a Lot of elements.

Thanks,

Comment: You want a dictionary.

Comment: Any reason you are using a string for the Guid, and not a `System.Guid`?

Comment: I create using System.Guid, but when I export - import I use string. Basically is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `Dictionary` should be faster

```
var customers = customerList.ToDictionary(x => x.uuid, x => x);

Customer c;

if(customers.TryGetValue("GUID I'm searching", out c)) 
   //  customer found
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Dictionary<Guid, Customer>` where each `Guid` identifies your specific customer.

Then, you can locate your customer using:

```
Customer cust; 
dictionary.TryGetValue(GuidHere, out cust);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an index by creating a dictionary with the GUID string as key and the object as value:

```
Dictionary<string, Customer> index = CustomerList.ToDictionary(c => c.uuid);
```

Now you can look up objects very fast:

```
Customer c = index["GUID I'm searching"];
```

If you don't know if the guid exists in the list:

```
Customer c;
if (index.TryGetValue("GUID I'm searching", out c) {
  // now c contains the customer
} else {
  // not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides a dictionary you could also sort it and then do a BinarySearch  Something like this

```
public class CustomerComparer : IComparer<customers>
{
    public int Compare(customers x, customers y)
    {
        return x.uuid.CompareTo(y.uuid);
    }
}
```

Now where ever you are using the CystomerList after it has been loaded you will need to sort it.  If you add more to the list I believe you would need to resort so just do it after everything is loaded and you'll only need to do it once

```
CustomerList.Sort(new CustomerComparer());

//now sorted you can do BinarySearch
int indx = CustomerList.BinarySearch(new customers() {uuid = "GUID I'm searching"}, new CustomerComparer());
```

You'll have to test to see if the sorting if worth the extra cost.